# How to create a diagnosticable tree with a depth bigger than 1?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to display a complex structure in the widget inspector by overriding `debugFillProperties`.

The issue I have is, the depth seems limited, at which point the displayed value is a `toString` of the object.

I'm trying to have such a tree:

```
MyClass
  + complexObject: Foo
    + object1: Bar 
       bar: 42
    + object2: Bar
       bar: 0
```

But the only thing I managed to get is the following:

```
MyClass
  + complexObject: Foo
     object1: Bar(bar: 42)
     object2: Bar(bar: 0)
```

[image: visual]

I tried the following:

```
@override
void debugFillProperties(DiagnosticPropertiesBuilder properties) {
  super.debugFillProperties(properties);
  properties.add(
    DiagnosticsProperty(
      'foo',
      Foo(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Where `Foo` is:

```
class Foo extends DiagnosticableTree{
  @override
  void debugFillProperties(DiagnosticPropertiesBuilder properties) {
    super.debugFillProperties(properties);
    properties.add(DiagnosticsProperty('object1', Bar(42)));
    properties.add(DiagnosticsProperty('object2', Bar(0)));
  }
}

class Bar extends Diagnosticable {
  final int value;

  Bar(this.value);

  @override
  void debugFillProperties(DiagnosticPropertiesBuilder properties) {
    super.debugFillProperties(properties);
    properties.add(DiagnosticsProperty('value', value));
  }
}
```